# how to read a large file in blocks efficiently in R

Tags: r, file-io

I am reading a large events file in R, close to 2 million lines, parsing each line into a set of event attributes and storing in my matrix. I pre-allocate a huge matrix (2 million events), read a small chunk from the file, repeatedly, and process it. But it is taking too long to process the file. I was wondering what I can do to improve the performance. Here is my code snippet:

```
numEvents <<- 2000000;
eventLog <<- matrix(0,nrow=numEvents,ncol=4);

loadEvents <- function(inputfile) {
    con <- file(inputfile, "r", blocking = FALSE)
    batch <- 1000
    lines <- readLines(con,n=batch)
    while(length(lines) > 0 && eventCount <= numEvents) {
        for (i in 1:length(lines))
            storeEvent(lines[i]); # processes and stores each event in eventlog
        lines <- readLines(con,n=batch)
    }
    close(con);
}
```

Do you think batch size is not optimal?

Any ideas here very much appreciated.

Comment: 2m rows doesn't seem terribly large to me. Your performance problems may not be related to reading the file, but that you haven't vectorized your processing function.

Comment: processing function is fairly simple. It reads the attributes from file and applies some conditions before storing it at the next index in event log. There is no scope for vectorization. I am thinking it might be possible to optimize the way I am reading the file..

Comment: Never say there is no scope for vectorization... can you show us how this parsing looks like?

Comment: it is a bit proprietary in nature so I cannot post it here. I tried to increase the batch size and it has a positive impact on performance. So I am trying to find the optimal batch size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue in my processing. I was using list as a map to contain mappings for events. List is not inherently a hash map so it can be quite slow. I changed it to use hash() and performance improved ten fold. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your case is a good case for an [R extension](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-R-API) (in C or C++)? But I don't know much R.

Comment: This package might be of some help to the original poster: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LaF/index.html It handles the C++ business behind the scenes. (Also note to the OP: don't use the global assignment operator: there be dragons....)